# Thread doesnt execute a class function

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am trying to call hear() through a thread and kill it when stop() is called. It is seen that the start() works fine but the thread doesn't seem to be calling the hear(). Where am I going wrong ? Thanks in Advance :)

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from threading import Thread
import time

class SpeechRecognizer():
    HEAR = True
    speech_recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
    
    def __init__(self,src_lang='hi-IN'):
        self.src_lang=src_lang
        self.hearing_thread = Thread(target=self.hear)

    def hear(self):
        print('in hearing')
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            self.speech_recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            while self.HEAR:
                audio = self.speech_recognizer.listen(source)
                text = self.speech_recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language=self.src_lang)
                print(text)

    def start(self):
        print('starting to hear')
        self.hearing_thread.start()


    def stop(self):
        self.HEAR = False
        self.hearing_thread.join()
        print('done hearing')

if __name__=='__main__':
    sr=SpeechRecognizer()
    sr.start()
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(1)
    sr.stop()
```

Comment: Re, "the thread doesn't seem to be calling the hear()" What is your reason for thinking so? Does it print, `in hearing`? If the program doesn't do what you want it to do, then what _does_ it do instead? I ran a version of your program in which I commented out the calls to the `speech_recognition` package, and it printed `in hearing` when I ran it.

Comment: Hi @SolomonSlow, Thanks a lot for your clarification. When I tried this code as a monolithic python code without the class and instances, the thread is executing just fine even with the speech_recognition package. It is only when I am defining it in class, I am not able to see the 'in hearing' statement. I just want to know if I am missing any decorators etc to get it to work.

Comment: `HEAR = True
speech_recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
def hear():

    print 'in hear'
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        speech_recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        while HEAR:

            audio = speech_recognizer.listen(source)
            text = speech_recognizer.recognize_google(audio,
                        language='hi-IN')
            print text

new_thread = Thread(target=hear)
new_thread.start()
for i in range(15):
    time.sleep(1)
HEAR = False
new_thread.join()
` This code snippet works just fine. But I wanted to keep it in a class. TIA !

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there is a naming conflict. Both the speech_recognition package and the class instance were named the same. It started working fine when I renamed the class instance from sr to a different name.